# Google sheets cell / formula not updating when new data is entered

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula in google sheets.  Even when the indexed cell from the range changes, the cell value does not update.

```
=IFERROR(index(TempRange1,53,6),"")
```

If I go in and edit the cell (say delete 53, hit enter, and then re-enter 53 and hit enter) it magically populates.

TempRange1 is created via a script, there is the possibility of as many as 12 cells referencing TempRange1 to TempRange12 all with the same issue when created.

Thoughts? I've tried turning off hardware acceleration in google chrome (as suggested by another post).  I'd definitely prefer not to go the script route.

Thanks

Comment: looks like script related. can you paste that script here?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]